# Cannot load the page when opening YouTube link in HTTPS on stock browser

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, stock-browser

When I try to play YouTube video in Android stock browser, it is showing blank screen.

**Log message:**

```
 Blocked URL: [blocked] The page at 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ij_0p_6qTss' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://...`: this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

If I try to play the same video with HTTP, it is playing fine. It seems like WebView is blocking redirection from HTTPS to HTTP.

can anyone clarify me how to bypass the error?

Comment: If i play the same video in Nexus 5 chrome browser it plays fine

Comment: I removed my comment since it's misguiding. Anyway, could you clarify the question? Do you want to know why stock browser blocks, or how to bypass this error on stock browser, or both, or..? Some browsers may ignore this and just load all contents anyway.

Comment: The browser is working correctly..Its a bug in the website as mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/webbrowser-app/+bug/1355120)..The reason it works on other browser is becuase some browsers still loads the page if there are mixed content and some browsers blocks the content..

Comment: I want to know how to bypass without ignoring ssl.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer because it may help someone.
I solved this by adding

> Settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);